# Solr : importing dynamic field names from XML with DIH and xpath

Tags: regex, xpath, solr, dataimporthandler, transformer-model

I'm indexing data from a XML file, with many fields like these declared in DataImportHandler's **dataconfig.xml** :

```
<field column="pos_A" xpath="/positions/pos_A/@pos" />
<field column="pos_B" xpath="/positions/pos_B/@pos" />
<field column="pos_C" xpath="/positions/pos_C/@pos" />
...
```

And one matching **dynamicField** declaration in **schema.xml** :

```
<dynamicField name="pos_*" type="sint" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a [transformer](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler#UploadingStructuredDataStoreDatawiththeDataImportHandler-Transformers) to dynamically generate the field names in **dataconfig.xml**, and have a single line, kinda like :

```
<field column="pos_{$1}" xpath="/positions/pos_(*)/@pos" />
```

(pardon my xpath and regex syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3251 The latest release claims that you can dynamically add fields to the schema. I tried to find documentation for the public interface, but not much luck so far.

>

```
SOLR-4658: In preparation for REST API requests that can modify the schema,
126   a "managed schema" is introduced.  
127   Add '<schemaFactory class="ManagedSchemaFactory" mutable="true"/>' to solrconfig.xml
128   in order to use it, and to enable schema modifications via REST API requests.
129   (Steve Rowe, Robert Muir)
```